# Spring web mvc helloword doesnt work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Just try to start up a web mvc helloworld project, but met small problem.

I have a simple controller, HelloController:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView printHello() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("hello");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

And a simple jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<body>
 <h1>Message :${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Spring config as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="se.ericsson.jcat.ebs.ecim" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

After running the webapp, I can access http://localhost:8080/hello, but it show me something like this:
Message :${message}

Instead of Message:Hello Spring MVC Framework

Thanks in advance.

Answer:
Finally, I find the error, after I add this small part in my web.xml, it back to normal.

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

Comment: I dont have form, just show a message. I reference the example from here:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm

Comment: I was thinking Spring2. Check out this great tutorial and see if it gives you some more direction: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: Thanks for your link, this example almost the same as my example, I dont find any diff between them.

Comment: Your `printHello` method is different than the tutorial you provided. They have `public String printHello(ModelMap model) {`. Try changing it to match the tutorial exactly and it might work

Comment: I try all of them, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Did you put in a breakpoint to confirm the Controller is actually being called? What are the Spring JAR files you're using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69909/discussion-between-ascalonian-and-tim).

Comment: If you really want to be productive with Spring, reading 5+ years old tutorials with a EOL'd Spring version (3.0 and 3.2 aren't supported anymore) won't do any good. Why not start with the official guides https://spring.io/guides ?

Answer (score 0):

Other stuff looks ok,except below line in your `spring config xml` file.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

update xml name space also like below.

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
```

Comment: You don't need `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in this case as `RequestMapping` and `Controller` are part of the default behavior

Comment: What about model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!") instead of addObject(...) ?

Comment: I also try it, and the same output.